# Difference between entropies as a similarity metric

Tags: entropy, similarities

The Shannon entropy of terms for two documents $d_1$ and $d_2$ is computed

$$\displaystyle H_1(X) = -\sum_{i=1}^n P(t_i)\cdot \log_2(P(t_i))\quad\text{and similar for}\quad H_2(X).$$

- Can the difference of two entropies in absolute value $\lvert H_1-H_2\rvert$ be used as a similarity metric?
- If so, is this used anywhere?

( I wasn't able to find any context that uses this difference. Instead, I've seen the [relative entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition) being used for this. I was able to find an example of how it's [computed here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/173221/90824) )

Comment: Using this similarity on its own is probably not useful, but as a feature in ML settings it will most likely be helpful

Comment: A log-likelihood distance is entropy-based.

Comment: @ttnphns sounds interesting, can you provide a link that describes it? preferably with an example of usage too